# SSH within PHP script

Tags: php, ssh

**preface**
I am setting up a web environment intended to be hosted on a local server strictly accessible on the local network. There's about 50 employees within the office and no employee has an assigned computer.

**problem**
Via an HTML form with parameters ('host', 'username', 'password'), the PHP will attempt an ssh.

**Main Point**
Basically I'm trying to find out how to interact with ssh from PHP (i.e. edit and view files/directories.

ie
user enters username, password into an html form. My php code takes this information and (if valid) ssh into their user on server. Giving them access to directories and files.

Comment: um er. just give them ssh clients. why use php

Comment: This is probably  [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd reformulate the question as "How to implement SSH access for 50 employees with no assigned computers". Using PHP is just one possible option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) to handle the SSH. Here is some simple code to get you started:

```
<div>
<?php

    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
    include('Net/SSH2.php');

    function display_home_directory($hostname, $username, $password) {
        $ssh = new Net_SSH2($hostname);
        if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {
            echo 'Login Failed';
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
        echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    display_home_directory('example.com', 'myusername', 'mypassword');
?>
</div>
```